# How do I prevent TailwindCSS table from expanding when many records are loaded?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, html-table, tailwind-css

I'm working on a table, styled with tailwind CSS which contains a number of records based on a records count filter. A typical record on this table looks like

[image: typical table record]

When I increase the number of records to 500, the reference ID and Account Name columns of the table expand. You can check the gif for more info.

[image: expanding table]

Here's the code for the table

```
        <table className="overflow-x-auto w-full border-separate space-y-9">
            <thead className="rounded-lg text-sm text-white bg-c-purple-100 w-full">
                <tr>
                    <th className="p-4">Client ID</th>
                    <th className="p-4">Reference ID</th>
                    <th className="p-4">Account name</th>
                    <th className="p-4">Bank</th>
                    <th className="p-4">Account Number</th>
                    <th className="p-4">Amount</th>
                    <th className="p-4">Country</th>
                    <th className="p-4">Date</th>
                    <th className="p-4">Email</th>
                    <th className="p-4">Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody className="border-separate text-xs">
                {values.map((val) => {
                    return (
                        <tr>
                            <td className="p-2 h-14 text-center text-c-purple-200">some-id</td>
                            <td className="p-2 h-14 text-center text-c-purple-200">some-ref</td>
                            <td className="p-2 h-14 text-center text-c-purple-200">some-name</td>
                            <td className="p-2 h-14 text-center text-c-purple-200">-</td>
                            <td className="p-2 h-14 text-center text-c-purple-200">some-account</td>
                            <td className="p-2 h-14 text-center text-c-purple-200">some-amount</td>
                            <td className="p-2 h-14 text-center text-c-purple-200">-</td>
                            <td className="p-2 h-14 text-center text-c-purple-200">some-date</td>
                            <td className="p-2 h-14 text-center text-c-purple-200">some-email</td>
                            <StatusTag status="cleared" />
                        </tr>
                    );
                })}
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

How do I prevent this table from expanding when I increase the number of records to 500?

Comment: How are you increasing the number of records to 500? Are you copy and pasting it to test or pulling in dynamic content.

Comment: I'm using a map to loop

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the tailwind table, maybe check the data you are loading from the map to see if it is the problem. You can copy-paste 500 <th> and <tr> just to be sure that its not the table.